# On mobile site; provide error message for comments that are too long

Tags: feature-request, comments, mobile-web

When attempting to add a comment on the mobile version of stack overflow that is too long to be allowed simply *nothing* happens. This is in contrast to the main version of the site where the text below indicates "too long by 16 characters".

I have myself tried to add a (slightly too long) comment and had the "add comment" button appear to be broken; I then tried reloading the page and then closing the entire browser and reloading before I eventually realised that my comment was too long.

My feature request is therefore that a pop up dialogue (similar to the mobile comment deletion confirmation dialogue) appears where a comment is invalid due to excessive length.

In case its supposed to do this already and this is a bug not a feature request; I’m using the default browser on Android 4.1.2 (Jelly bean) on a Samsung galaxy s3.

Comment: Already reported for too short comments, too long is the same.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Fair enough, I was searching only for too long, but there seems to be several too shorts. Looks like i'm unusual in my comment length (I can't remember ever having a too short comment)

Comment: Regardless I shall leave this here as a pointer towards the main question for long commenters such as myself (voting to close my own question)