# I've asked a duplicate question. Now what?

Tags: support, duplicate-questions

I asked a duplicate question and the community flagged it as duplicate. So I accepted it as duplicate. Now what? Am I supposed to delete it? I ask this because even after accepting that it is a duplicate, people are down voting.

Comment: @Catijan, yes it does!

Comment: Oh the irony. :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, if they are really duplicates and they have no answer, they are probably not of that much value to the community. Hence you *could* delete them. Note that duplicates has a significant value in finding the duplicate question. Your question might contain keywords the original doesn't have, so keep them if you wish.

I should warn you though that asking multiple duplicate questions may lead to a [question ban](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/188292/245360) (deleting posts do count toward a question ban too). The problem with those questions is: there usually isn't much to improve so they get reopened which may get you out of a ban.

So instead of worrying whether you should delete them or not, worry about asking questions that are a duplicate. That is much worse than actually deleting them.