# How do I fix poorly-received questions if it was deemed as a duplicate (when trying to reclaim the ability to post questions)?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, post-ban

Due to some questions of questionable quality from the times when I was still at school I am unable to post questions on Stack Overflow. I want to make my amends and the [Help Centre](https://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans) suggest I should "begin by fixing my existing questions".

What if the only problem with the question was that it was deemed to be a duplicate (e.g. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40193823/better-way-to-write-assign-a-or-if-not-possible-b))? There is literally nothing I could change about the question to make it a non-duplicate unless I am willing to totally change the subject, which would be counterproductive.

Comment: @PolyGeo oh the irony...

Comment: Your deleted questions are the ones weighing you down.

Comment: @Won't - and with the deleted questions there is no way to repent for one's sins, is there?

Comment: Not sins, just screw-ups.  Flag one of your questions with the Other reason and ask the mod to undelete, or to send you a mod message with links to your deleted questions.  You can then edit them and try to get them undeleted (easy if you did it, hard if others did, needs another flag if a mod deleted it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [question that you cite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40193823) should not be contributing very much to your question ban because it has a net 0 vote.

It seems that duplicates do contribute (see [Will asking too many duplicate questions lead to a question ban?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188291)) but the main contributors, which you should focus on improving, are those which have been deleted, downvoted, and/or closed for other reasons.

Nevertheless, if you can edit a question closed as a duplicate, so that it is no longer a duplicate, then you will be even further along the path to redemption for your account.